# Find the variable with the most data in dataset

Tags: r

I have a technical question for you, please.

```
STATION NOM LONGITUDE   LATITUDE    ALTITUDE    DATE    RR  DRR TM  DG  TNTXM   FFM DXI HNEIGEF NEIGETOT06
34008001    LES AIRES(LA GARENE)    3`06'30"E   43`35'00"N  190 2006/01/01  3.2     8.2     7.3         0   0
34008001    LES AIRES(LA GARENE)    3`06'30"E   43`35'00"N  190 2006/01/02  0       7.4     8           0   0
34008001    LES AIRES(LA GARENE)    3`06'30"E   43`35'00"N  190 2006/01/03  0       6       6.6         0   0
34008001    LES AIRES(LA GARENE)    3`06'30"E   43`35'00"N  190 2006/01/04  0       3.5     5.8         0   0
34008001    LES AIRES(LA GARENE)    3`06'30"E   43`35'00"N  190 2006/01/05  2       -0.4        -0.4            1   0
34008001    LES AIRES(LA GARENE)    3`06'30"E   43`35'00"N  190 2006/01/06  35.4        4.1     3.5         0   1
34008001    LES AIRES(LA GARENE)    3`06'30"E   43`35'00"N  190 2006/01/07  10      5.7     5.8         0   0
34008001    LES AIRES(LA GARENE)    3`06'30"E   43`35'00"N  190 2006/01/08  17.4        6       5.9         0   0
34008001    LES AIRES(LA GARENE)    3`06'30"E   43`35'00"N  190 2006/01/09  24.6        5.3     5.3         0   0
34008001    LES AIRES(LA GARENE)    3`06'30"E   43`35'00"N  190 2006/01/10  0.2     5.3     8.4         0   0
34008001    LES AIRES(LA GARENE)    3`06'30"E   43`35'00"N  190 2006/01/11  0.2     1       3.3         0   0
34008001    LES AIRES(LA GARENE)    3`06'30"E   43`35'00"N  190 2006/01/12  0.2     4.8     6.1         0   0
34008001    LES AIRES(LA GARENE)    3`06'30"E   43`35'00"N  190 2006/01/13  1.4     3.7     3.6         0   0
34008001    LES AIRES(LA GARENE)    3`06'30"E   43`35'00"N  190 2006/01/14  1.8     5.3     5.7         0   0
34008001    LES AIRES(LA GARENE)    3`06'30"E   43`35'00"N  190 2006/01/15  39.2        5.2     5.5         0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/14  0                           0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/15  28                          0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/16  0                           0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/17  0.6                         0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/18  0                           0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/19  0                           0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/20  0                           0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/21  0                           0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/22  0                           0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/23  0                           0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/24  0                           0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/25  7.5                         0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/26  0                           0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/27  0                           0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/28  0                           0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/29  0                           0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/30  0                           0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/08/31  0                           0   0
34010001    ANIANE(GEND.)   3`34'54"E   43`40'54"N  65  2006/09/01  0                               
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/10/20  4       16.6    0   17.5    1.8 140     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/10/21  23.6        17  0   16.7    2.6 140     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/10/22  0       11.5    0   11.4    4.9 320     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/10/23  0.4     9.8 0   10.4    2.8 340     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/10/24  0.8     11.6    0   11.6    1.1 20      
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/10/25  0.2     14.6    0   15.6    2.8 340     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/10/26  0       14  0   14.8    2.7 340     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/10/27  5.4     13.3    0   14.3    1   180     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/10/28  2.6     9.8 0   10.1    3.8 340     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/10/29  0       6.8 0   7.1 5.4 340     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/10/30  1.8     4   0   3.8 1.2 260     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/10/31  0.8     10.9    0   9.2 3.1 120     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/11/01  11.8        14.9    0   15  4.9 100     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/11/02  36      13  0   13.2    5.3 100     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/11/03  0.2     10.3    0   11.3    2.5 120     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/11/04  27.8        10.2    0   10.3    1.7 320     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/11/05  13.6        9   0   9.1 1.3 300     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/11/06  0.4     9.3 0   9.4 1.3 320     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/11/07  0       10.2    0   11.1    1.4 360     
34028003    BEDARIEUX(AERODROME)    3`08'42"E   43`38'24"N  373 2008/11/08  0.4     10  0   12.1    1.2 120
```

I have weather data. From variable "RR" to "NEIGETOT06" they are meteorological parameters (9 variables). The problem is that I have very well informed stations and others much less informed. For some stations there are variables with only N'A.

I would like to know which stations have the most data. I would like to find a function that would tell me which are the stations with the most variables filled and which are the stations with the less filled variables. For example station 1 and 2, 6 variables with information (ex RR, DRR ...), stations 3-4, 4 variables with information ... Do you think it would be possible please?

Thank you all!

Comment: Please use `dput` to share a sample of your data. the various backticks, single and double quotes makes it impossibly tedious to load your data as is. Also, in your sample data I do not see and `NA` values...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution (based on a similar dataset in which there's actually missing values):

```
rbindlist(lapply(unique(df$STATION), function(m) data.frame(STATION = m, NonNAValues = sum(!is.na(df[df$STATION == m, ])))))
```

What it does: per station, get the number of all non-NA values (in all columns).

Output:

```
          STATION NonNAValues
 1:      34010001             448
 2:      34028003             392
 3:      34028007             975
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:
It might be better suited for numeric variables and will not be suitable for many variables.

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor,as.numeric) %>% 
map_dbl(~sum(.x)) %>% 
  sort(decreasing = T)
```

If you're only interested in numeric variables then:

```
iris %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  map_dbl(~sum(.x))
```

Find Missing Values? Then:

```
iris %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  map_dbl(~sum(is.na(.x)))
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody,

may be a solution like that :

```
testdata <- matrix(0, nrow = 3000, ncol = 1)

ncol <- c(7:15)
for(i in 1:length(testdata)){
    cat(i,"\r")
  testdata[i] <- length(which(!is.na(WEATHER[i, ncol])))
}
```

follow :

```
WEATHER_test <- cbind.data.frame(WEATHER, testdata)
testest <- as.matrix(tapply(WEATHER_test$testdata, WEATHER_test$NOM, FUN = "mean"))
```

?